# Proof on Dyadic Trees [Smullyan: First-Order Logic, chapter 1, section 0]

Tags: logic, order-theory, trees

I'm having difficult with a proof from Smullyan's *First-Order Logic*, Chapter 1 Section 0 (Reprint, Dover 1968, p. 4):

> **Prove:**
>
> In a dyadic tree, define x to be to the left of y if there is a junction point whose left successor dominates x and whose right successor dominates y.  Prove that if x is to the left of y and y is to the left of z, then x is to the left of z.
>
> **Relevant definitions:**
>
> 1. *Dyadic Tree:* a tree in which each junction point has exactly 2 successors
> 2. *x dominates y*: point x is above point y in the tree, or x is identical to y

So far, I have this for the proof:

1. x is to the left of y.  So there is some junction j1 whose left successor s1 dominates x, and whose right successor s2 dominates y
2. y is to the left of z.  So there is some junction j2 whose left successor s3 dominates y, and whose right successor s4 dominates z

I'm pretty sure what I need to prove from 1 and 2 is:

> There is some junction j3 whose left successor s5 dominates x, and whose right successor s6 dominates z.  So x is to the left of z.

So far, I've tried a proof that begins with cases (j1=j2; j1 dominates j2; j2 dominates j1; j1 and j2 are the let and right successors of j); and I've tried to work out a proof whereby every successor to s1 is to the left of every successor of s2, etc., but I get stuck each time.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that we need *induction* on the lenght of the tree. We can think to a tree of lenght $n+1$ as "made of" two "sub-trees" of lenght $\le n$ joined by a new "root". If the property hold for lenght $n$, when we join them, we have that the "left-sub" is on the left of "right-sub". Consider then the case when the three vertices $x,y,z$ are not all in the same sub (but of course two of them must be...

Answer (score 0):

Label each vertex $x,y,z$ uniquely as a sequence $S$ of $n$ elements drawn from $\{L,R\}$ according to the path required to reach them from some vertex that dominates them all.  (The choice can be arbitrary, but choose the closest for simplicity).

Define an ordering $>$ on $x,y,z$ by setting $S_a>S_b$ if $S_a$ has an $R$ rather than an $L$ in the first position, and $S_b>S_a$ if $S_a$ has an $L$ rather than an $R$, and continue to apply the same ordering rule for each successive letter $R,L$ in your sequence, making each concatenation an [end-extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_extension) - i.e. every choice of ${R,L}$ in position $n$ takes precedence in determining the ordering, over the choice in position $n+1$ and all that follow.

By the Euclidean algorithm your ordering $>$ is a wellorder.  It follows that your set is well-ordered from left to right by $>$ and therefore if $y>x$ and $z>y$ it follows from transitivity of $>$ that $z>x$.

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of a similar way to prove transitivity as mentioned by Curious Yogurt, and it goes as follows: Let's consider that we have three points $x$, $y$, and $z$ in a dyadic tree $\mathcal{T}$.

First, let's assume $x$ is to the left of $y$. This implies the existence of a junction point $j_1$ in $\mathcal{T}$ such that the left successor of $j_1$ dominates $x$, and the right successor of $j_1$ dominates $y$.

Next, consider that $y$ is to the left of $z$. Consequently, there is another junction point $j_2$ where the left successor of $j_2$ dominates $y$, and its right successor dominates $z$.

Given that both $j_1$ and $j_2$ dominate $y$, and since $\mathcal{T}$ is a dyadic tree (implying $j_1 \neq j_2$), we have two scenarios:

- If $j_1$ dominates $j_2$: Since $x$ is dominated by the left successor of $j_1$, and both $y$ and $z$ are dominated by the right successor of $j_1$, it follows that $x$ is left of $z$.
- If $j_2$ dominates $j_1$: Given $y$ is dominated by the left successor of $j_2$ and $x$ is also dominated by the left successor of $j_2$, this leads to the conclusion that $x$ is left of $z$.

Therefore, we can conclude that if $x$ is left of $y$ and $y$ is left of $z$ in a dyadic tree $\mathcal{T}$, then $x$ is indeed left of $z$.